# Bootstrap popover does not show up

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
```

```css
.edit-list-element{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 214px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="List options" data-content="Some content inside popover"><span class="glyphicon list-glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal option-list-img"></span></a>
```

I read lot of similar posts over here but none of offered ways worked.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you added your CSS for `.edit-list-element`? I can't tell if it's in your markup.

Comment: What JS scripts are you including? Did you make sure JQuery is loaded first before bootstrap? or have you set the scripts to async? or are you using another library that conflicts with say $ object

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you've included the required css and scripts to run bootstrap.
Kindly check the code below.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="List options" data-content="Some content inside popover"><span class="glyphicon list-glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal option-list-img"></span></a>
```

Comment: All of them are included -_-